# Project Euler #2 - Python v3.2.3

Tags: python, fibonacci, memoization

I'm having trouble with [problem 2](https://projecteuler.net/problem=2) on Project Euler. The objective is to find the sum of the even-valued terms in the Fibonacci sequence whose values do not exceed four million. For some reason, I keep getting 0 as my output. What am I doing wrong?

```
total = 0
count = 0
term = 0
fibonacciMemo = {0:0, 1:1}

def main ():
    term = fibonacci (count)
    while (term <= 4000000):
        if (term % 2 == 0):
            total += term
        count += 1

def fibonacci (n):
    if not n in fibonacciMemo:
        fibonacciMemo [n] = fibonacci (n - 1) + fibonacci (n - 2)
    return fibonacciMemo [n]

print (total)
```

Comment: Are you coming from a Java or C background? In python `main` is not called automatically. You'll need to explicitly call your function in order for it to execute.

Comment: Yeah, I have a C++ background. I'm just starting to pick up Python. Good to know that main isn't automatic - thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some issues:

- You're never calling the `main` function. You must explicitly call it for it to be executed.
- The assignments to variables `term`, `count`, `total` in `main` will not write to the global variables. Instead, distinct local variables with the same names will be created, and the global variables will still have the value `0` even after `main` is called.

  One way to fix this is to add the line `global term, count, total` in `main`. But this is bad design. Much better is to remove the global variables (make them all local to `main`), and have `main` return the value of `total`. Then `print(main())` will show the result.
- You only call `fibonacci` once in `main` - you'll want to put that inside the loop. Otherwise the loop will run infinitely since `term` is never updated.

Answer (score 4):

It is because you never call main or fibonacci.
You just assign

```
total = 0
count = 0
term = 0
fibonacciMemo = {0:0, 1:1}
```

and then

```
print (total)
```

If you want to execute `main`, you have to explicitly call it, e.g. by putting `main()` in front of `print (total)`

You have another problem in your code. You attempt to increment the global variable `total` from within a function. That won't work, unless you declare total `global` to this function. Do so by putting `global total` in the function before you first use total. Same problem with count and term.
And it seems you have a problem in your control flow, too. This won't generate the right answer.

Answer (score 2):

Add this line to the bottom of your script:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

That will call `main()` when you run the file as a Python script.

BTW there is a much better solution to the Project Euler problem, you can generate the even Fibonacci terms directly instead of filtering. Make a habit of looking for smart solutions now, or you will hit a wall when the problems get challenging.

Comment: Ah, okay. I didn't even realize that that was an inefficient solution. Thanks!